# Updating two columns in the same table, using group by?

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-update

I have two empty columns in a table. I want to populate these columns based off conditions. The first column should be updated with the total HR's from a batter. The second column should be updated with their highest Batting Average. I have tried:

```
UPDATE Spring_2021_BaseBall.dbo.People 
SET [Total_HR] = (SELECT SUM(HR)
                  FROM Spring_2021_BaseBall.dbo.Batting
                  GROUP BY playerid),
     [High_BA] = (SELECT playerID, 
                  FROM Spring_2021_BaseBall.dbo.Batting
                  GROUP BY playerid) B                       
WHERE A.playerid = B.playerid
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation to bring them together:

```
UPDATE p
    SET Total_HR = b.Total_HR,
        High_BA =  b.High_BA
    FROM Spring_2021_BaseBall.dbo.People p JOIN
         (SELECT SUM(HR) as SUM_hr, MAX(BA) as High_BA
          FROM Spring_2021_BaseBall.dbo.Batting
          GROUP BY playerid 
         ) b
         ON b.playerid = p.playerid ;
```